# SAS: sum of multiple rows and looping through all of them

Tags: sas

I would like to generate a new column that can be derived from an existing one as follows:

Row 1 of the new column is the sum of all entries from the first 21 rows of the given column.

Row 2 is again the sum of all entries from the next 21 rows (starting from row 2 of the already given column).

and so on.

small example:

```
 GivenColumn       NewColumn   
-----------------------------
  1                    15          
  2                    14        
  3                    12        
  4                     9        
  5                     5
```

Is there an easy way to do this? In Python, I would loop through all rows and thus achieve my desired result.

Thank you!

Comment: Your example only has 5 observations, but you mentioned groups of 21.  Should you example have multiple groups of 5 observations?  Is there already another variable that indicate why the 21 (or 5) observations should be considered part of the same group?  Or are you in possession of external knowledge that is not reflected in the actual data the let's you know the group size should be 21 (or 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forward rolling sum can be computed by using two separate SET statements reading the same data set and storing the forward elements in a cyclically indexed temporary array.

Example (updated):

For 21 items, change the 3's to 21's.

Change then %let N= from 1 to 10 and submit to convince yourself.

```
data have;
  call streaminit(231108);
  do id = 1 to 6;
    x = rand('integer',10);
    x = id;
    output;
  end;
  format id x 6.;
run;

%let N = 3 ;

data want(keep=x xfrsum&N);
  set have ;

  label xfrsum&N = "x forward rolling sum &";

  array xs[&N] _temporary_ ;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    do _n_ = 1 to &N while(not eoforward);
      link xf;
    end;
    if eoforward then _k_ = dim(xs);
  end;

  xfrsum&N = sum(of xs(*));

xf:
  _k_ + 1;
  if _k_ > dim(xs) then _k_ = 1;

  if not eoforward then do ;
    set have (rename=x=xf) end=eoforward;
    xs(_k_) = xf;
  end ;
  else
    xs(_k_) = .;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this almost solves my problem. If I get to the end of the data and there are not enough rows left to add up, this should be ignored and an invisible zero should be added. So if we assume there are 11 rows like in your screenshot. The number in row 10 should be 46 (23+23+0) and the number in row 11 just the 23 (23+0+0).

Comment: See updated example.

Answer (score 2):

If you have SAS/ETS, `proc expand` makes easy work of this. The idea is:

- Get the number of observations in the dataset
- Reverse the column
- Calculate a moving sum exactly *nobs* long
- Reverse the new column

```
%let dsid = %sysfunc(open(have));
%let nobs = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid, nlobs));
%let rc   = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));
    
proc expand data=have out=want(drop=time);
    convert GivenColumn = NewColumn / transform=(reverse movsum &nobs reverse);
run;
```

```
NewColumn   GivenColumn
15          1
14          2
12          3
9           4
5           5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data have;
input GivenColumn;
datalines; 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
;

proc sql;
   create table want as
   select GivenColumn
        , (select sum(GivenColumn)
          from have as b 
          where a.GivenColumn <= b.GivenColumn)
          as NewColumn
   from have as a
   ;
quit;
```

**Result:**

```
GivenColumn NewColumn
1           15
2           14
3           12
4           9
5           5
```

Comment: Perhaps I didn't express myself clearly enough. The numbers in the given column are not necessarily in ascending order. 

Also, the condition that the next 21 rows (5 rows in my example) should be totalled has not been taken into account, has it? 

The new rows always result from the sum of rows 1-21, 2-22, 3-23 etc. If, for example, there are not enough lines left, zeros are simply added. As in my example, the last line (5+0+0+0+0)

Comment: Why 5 (or 21) and not 3 of 147?  What is the variable in the dataset that indicates that these particular 21 values should be grouped?

Answer (score 0):

If you had the data sorted in the opposite order your "NewColumn" variable is just a running sum.

Let's replicate your example 5 observations, only sorted in the opposite order:

```
data have;
  do OldVariable=5 to 1 by -1;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Then just use a SUM statement to create you new variable that is a running sum of the old variable.

```
data want;
  set have;
  NewVariable + OldVariable;
run;
```

But you also mentioned groups of 21.  What is the variable in the dataset that indicates which observation belong to the same group?  What is the variable in the dataset that indicates the order you want to sum the values?

Assuming your real data has more variables, say and GROUP variable to identify the group, and a DATE variable to indicate the ORDER.  Then your larger problem might be solved by first sorting the data in the right order and then processing it by group.

```
proc sort data=HAVE ;
   by group descending date;
run;
data want;
  set have;
  by group;
  if first.group then NewVariable = 0;
  NewVariable + OldVariable;
run;
```

You could then re sort it by GROUP and DATE to get them back into ascending order.

If you are really forced to use your outside knowledge that the first 21 observations should be summed then you could do it with two DO loops where each one reads in the next 21 observations. The first will calculate the sum and the second will do the subtraction and output the observations.

```
data want;
  do i=1 to 21 until (eof1);
     set have end=eof1;
     NewVariable = sum(OldVariable,NewVariable);
  end;
  do i=1 to 21 until (eof2);
     set have end=eof2; 
     output;
     NewVariable = sum(Newvariable,-OldVariable);
  end;
  drop i;
run;
```